# Sum of hybrid data frames depending on multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe

This is a more complex follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15041825/1281870). The answer there was to use a matrix, but that doesn't work with data frames having values of different modes.

I want to combine data frames of *different sizes*, with character and integer columns, and calculate their sum depending on *multiple conditions*.

### Conditions

1. sums are only calculated for those rows that have a matching "Name"-value
2. sums are calculated for matching column names only
3. if a cell in `df4` is not 0 and not NA, the sum should be `df3 + df4`
4. else the sum should be `df1 + df2 + df3`

### Example

```
> df1 <- data.frame(Name=c("Joe","Ann","Lee","Dan"), "1"=c(0,1,5,2), "2"=c(3,1,0,0), "3"=c(2,0,2,2), "4"=c(2,1,3,4))
> df1
  Name X1 X2 X3 X4
1  Joe  0  3  2  2
2  Ann  1  1  0  1
3  Lee  5  0  2  3
4  Dan  2  0  2  4

> df2 <- data.frame(Name=c("Joe","Ann","Ken"), "1"=c(3,4,1), "2"=c(2,3,0), "3"=c(2,4,3))
> df2
  Name X1 X2 X3
1  Joe  3  2  2
2  Ann  4  3  4
3  Ken  1  0  3

> df3 <- data.frame(Name=c("Lee","Ben"), "1"=c(1,3), "2"=c(3,4), "3"=c(4,3))
> df3
  Name X1 X2 X3
1  Lee  1  3  4
2  Ben  3  4  3
```

The condition depends on this frame:

```
> df4 <- data.frame(Name=c("Lee","Ann","Dan"), "1"=c(6,0,NA), "2"=c(0,0,4), "3"=c(0,NA,0))
> df4
   Name  X1  X2  X3
1   Lee   6   0   0
2   Ann   0   0  NA 
3   Dan  NA   4   0
```

With the above examples, this is the expected result (* values depend on df4):

```
> dfsum
  Name  X1  X2  X3  X4
1  Joe   3   5   4   2
2  Ann   5   4   4   1
3  Lee   7*  3   6   3
4  Dan   2   4*  2   4
5  Ken   1   0   3  NA
6  Ben   3   4   3  NA
```

### Possible steps?

First expand df1, df2, df3, df4 to 5 columns and 6 rows, fill missing data with NA.

Then for each data frame:

1. sort rows by "Name"
2. separate "Name" column from "X1"..."X4"
3. transform "X1"..."X4" columns to matrix
4. calculate sums of the matrices like in the answer to my other question **but** with the additional condition 1
5. transform result matrix to data frame
6. cbind the "Name" column with the result data frame

### How can this be done in R?

---

#### Solution

@Ricardo Saporta's solution works with little changes:

Add `, padValue=NA)` in the four addCols().

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15057885/1281870), replace the definitions of sumD3D4 and dtsum with:

```
plus <- function(x) {
  if(all(is.na(x))){
    c(x[0],NA)} else {
      sum(x,na.rm = TRUE)}
}

sumD3D4  <- setkey(rbind(dt3, dt4)[,lapply(.SD, plus), by = Name], "Name")
dtsum <- setkey(rbind(dt1, dt2, dt3)[, lapply(.SD, plus), by=Name], "Name")
```

Comment: It appears that the only role of the `character`s are the names.  Is that correct ? If so, you can still use the matrix method recommended and apply the strings to `rownames(mtrx)`

Comment: Also, regarding the different number of columns, would it be okay to add dummy columns to filled with 0's so that all df's are the same width?

Comment: They should be NA, but is it possible to treat NAs as 0's when calculating the sum of two matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use data.table instead of data.frame, you could use its `by=xxxx` feature, to add by name. 
The code below should give you your expected results.

Please note that I am padding the data.tables with extra empty columns.  However, we compute `condTrue` prior to then.

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(df1)
dt2 <- data.table(df2)
dt3 <- data.table(df3)
dt4 <- data.table(df4)

# make sure all dt's have the same columns 
#-----------------------------------------#

# identify which dt4 satisfy the condition 
condTrue <- as.data.table(which(!(is.na(dt4) | dt4==0), arr.ind=TRUE))

# ignore column "Name" from dt4
condTrue <- condTrue[col>1]

# convert from (row, col) index to ("Name", columnName) 
condTrue <- data.table(Name=dt4[condTrue$row, Name], colm=names(dt4)[condTrue$col], key="Name")


# First make a list of all the unique column names
allColumnNames <- unique(c(names(dt1), names(dt2), names(dt3), names(dt4)))

# add columns as necessary, using addCols (definted below)
addCols(dt1, allColumnNames)
addCols(dt2, allColumnNames)
addCols(dt3, allColumnNames)
addCols(dt4, allColumnNames)


sumD3D4  <- setkey(rbind(dt3, dt4)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=Name], "Name")
dtsum    <- setkey(rbind(dt1, dt2, dt3)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=Name], "Name")

for (Nam in condTrue$Name) {
  colsRepl <- condTrue[.(Nam)]$colm
  valsRepl <- unlist(sumD3D4[.(Nam), c(colsRepl), with=FALSE])
  dtsum[.(Nam), c(colsRepl) :=  as.list(valsRepl)]
}

dtsum
#    Name 1 2 3 4
# 1:  Ann 5 4 4 1
# 2:  Ben 3 4 3 0
# 3:  Dan 2 4 2 4
# 4:  Joe 3 5 4 2
# 5:  Ken 1 0 3 0
# 6:  Lee 7 3 6 3
```

---

```
addCols <- function(x, cols, padValue=0)  {
  # adds to x any columns that are in cols but not in x
  # Returns TRUE  if columns were added
  #         FALSE if no columns added 
  colsMissing <- setdiff(cols, names(x))

  # grab the actual DT name that was passed to function
  dtName <- as.character(match.call()[2])

  if (length(colsMissing)) {
    get(dtName, envir=parent.frame(1))[, c(colsMissing) := padValue]  
    return(TRUE)
  }

  return(FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Nice. Sometimes I wonder how people get in these predicaments.  But solving them poses some interesting puzzles.

Comment: Very nice. But how do I keep NA's for Ken and Ben in column X4?

Comment: @R-obert, your comment above said you wanted to treat the NA's as 0's.   Note that the NA's you are looking for are present as 0's in column 4.  If you would like to use NA's instead, simply add `, padValue=NA)` in the four `addCols()` statements.    Note however, that it will then make all NA cols into NA's in the results.  If you want the NA's to be passed only selectively, you need to add more conditional statements above.

Comment: My comment above was unclear. I would like to use NA's but it still doesn't work. Adding `, padValue=NA)` results in: `Error in [.data.table'(dtsum, .(Nam), ':='(c(colsRepl), as.list(valsRepl))): Type of RHS ('double') must match LHS ('integer'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)`

Comment: I'm sorry @R-obert, but its still not very clear what specifically _"to use NA's"_ means.  Where would you like no use them, how would you like to use them?

Comment: As for the error, where are you seeing it? In the `addcols()` call, in the `for` loop at the end?  You can try wrapping the offending RHS in `as.integer`. If that doesn't help, please consider posting it as a new question. As it might get too cumbersome to trouble shoot in the comments.  Thanks :)

Comment: Wrapping didn't work. But I can't open a new question because this question already asks for NA in column X4 for Ken and Ben in `dfsum`...

Comment: Using the sample data you provided above, I'm not getting the same error you are getting. There must be some additional information that is missing.  Again, please consider opening a new question and linking back to this one.  Thank you

Comment: Moreover, if you want to add NA's for only a *select set of rows* you need to somehow isolate those rows.  You can that using the same methodoly that is used for adding columns, you would add missing rows to `df4` with values of NA in the columns that you want to be NA.  If you want to add things __conditionally__ you need to introduce the __Conditions.__

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25052/discussion-between-r-obert-and-ricardo-saporta)