# Treat NA as zero only when adding a number

Tags: r, data.table, na

When calculating the sum of two data tables, `NA+n=NA`.

```
> dt1 <- data.table(Name=c("Joe","Ann"), "1"=c(0,NA), "2"=c(3,NA))
> dt1
   Name  1  2
1:  Joe  0  3
2:  Ann NA NA
> dt2 <- data.table(Name=c("Joe","Ann"), "1"=c(0,NA), "2"=c(2,3))
> dt2
   Name  1 2
1:  Joe  0 2
2:  Ann NA 3
> dtsum  <- rbind(dt1, dt2)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=Name]
> dtsum
   Name  1  2
1:  Joe  0  5
2:  Ann NA NA
```

I don't want to substitute all NA's with 0. What I want is `NA+NA=NA` and `NA+n=n` to get the following result:

```
   Name  1  2
1:  Joe  0  5
2:  Ann NA  3
```

How is this done in R?

**UPDATE: removed typo in dt1**

Comment: If you link back to your previous question, folks can better understand what you are hoping to accomplish and can offer better help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044342/sum-of-hybrid-data-frames-depending-on-multiple-conditions-in-r

Comment: I have isolated the problem here. The other question is now solved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define your own function to act as you want

```
plus <- function(x) {
 if(all(is.na(x))){
   c(x[0],NA)} else {
   sum(x,na.rm = TRUE)}
 }


rbind(dt1, dt2)[,lapply(.SD, plus), by = Name]
```

Comment: (+1) neat trick with `x[0]`! I'll remember it for the next time.

Comment: You could also use `as(NA, class(x))`, I haven't benchmarked to see which would be faster.

Comment: @R-obert, mnel's function here is great.  You can put it right in to your previous question, simply replacing `sum` with mnel's `plus` in the two lines of `DTsum <- ...` and `sumD3D4 <- ...`

Comment: +1 Very nice, I can put this into one of my existing functions - thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
dtsum  <- rbind(dt1, dt2)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), as.numeric(NA), sum(x, na.rm=T))), by=Name]
```

(includes @Arun's suggestion)
`na.rm=TRUE` is very useful to remember

Comment: Sorry, just realised this will give `NA + NA = 0`, which I don't think is what you want

Comment: at no point does the OP calculate `NA+NA` (given the way `dt1` and `dt2` are defined (not how they are shown)`

Comment: @mnel fixed a typo in the question

Comment: Just use an `ifelse`. It is not that complicated. `rbind(dt1, dt2)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), as.numeric(NA),          sum(x, na.rm=T))), by=Name]`

Comment: @Arun, see my answer which should help preserve the class of `x` if it is an integer.