# R aggregation with sum function gives the value 0 when it sums NA

Tags: r, data.table, na, zero

I have a problem with several aggregation function in R.
I have this dataset :

```
df = data.table(x = rep(letters[1:3], each = 4), y = seq(15,26))

# I put NA value for "b" levels    
df[5:8,2] = NA
```

For the "b" level of x, I only have NA values for y column and the result of aggregation replaces the sum of (NA+NA+...+NA) by 0 instead of NA (what I want...)

```
agg1 = ddply(df, .(x), summarize, agg = sum(y, na.rm = TRUE))

agg2 = aggregate(y ~ x, data = df, sum, na.action=na.pass, na.rm=TRUE)

agg3 = df[, agg := sum(y, na.rm = TRUE), by = list(x)]
```

I can't remove the NA value of my dataset to overpass this problem because of the complexity of my real dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need is to remove the na.rm=T

```
  agg2<-  aggregate(y ~ x, data = df, sum, na.action=na.pass)
```

and this is the result :

```
> agg2
  x  y
1 a 66
2 b NA
3 c 98
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but if  you had this line : df[11,2] = NA
"a" factor is full of numbers, "b" factor is full of NA and "c" factor as numbers and NA. Then the solution you gave doesn't work for this case.

Comment: you can find your answer here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057769/treat-na-as-zero-only-when-adding-a-number)

`plus <- function(x) {
    if(all(is.na(x))){
        c(x[0],NA)} else {
            sum(x,na.rm = TRUE)}
}


df[,lapply(.SD, plus), by = x]`