# Sum to 0 if vector includes NAs and 0?

Tags: r

I've run into an interesting problem trying to make my R results line up with SPSS results from a colleague. It seems that in SPSS, when summing, `NA + NA = NA` and `0 + NA = 0`, but in R, I cannot seem to reproduce this. In R, either both sum to NA or both sum to 0. However, in my case, if all values in the sum command are missing, they should be NA, but it there is at least one 0, it should be 0.

```
nana <- c(NA, NA)
na0 <- c(NA, 0)
sum(nana) # sums to NA
sum(na0) # sums to  NA
sum(nana, na.rm=T) # sums to 0
sum(na0, na.rm=T) # sums to 0
```

I found this answer, [Treat NA as zero only when adding a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057769/treat-na-as-zero-only-when-adding-a-number), but it doesn't work when using `sum` across multiple vectors, as in `sum(x,y,z)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checks in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057769/treat-na-as-zero-only-when-adding-a-number) can be extended to

```
plus <- function(...) {
 if(all(is.na(do.call(c, list(...))))){
   NA} else {
   sum(...,na.rm = TRUE)}
 }
plus(c(NA, 3), 1:5)
# [1] 18
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you just want to make your own custom function to get that functionality.

```
modSum <- function(x){
  if(all(is.na(x))){return(NA)}
  sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Seeing it in action

```
> nana <- c(NA, NA)
> na0 <- c(NA, 0)
> sum(nana) # sums to NA
[1] NA
> sum(na0) # sums to  NA
[1] NA
> sum(nana, na.rm=T) # sums to 0
[1] 0
> sum(na0, na.rm=T) # sums to 0
[1] 0
> modSum(nana)
[1] NA
> modSum(na0)
[1] 0
```